# Finding the maximum of $5\sin x+4\sin 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

How does one find the maximum value of 
$$
5\sin(x)+4\sin(2x)
$$
without using calculus?

Comment: Wait, Kim Jong Un is on math.stackexchange? Where's Dennis Rodman?

Comment: Note that $\sin ( 2x ) = 2 \sin ( x ) \cos (x )$

Answer (score 2):

Put $t=\sin x$ and make an equation only in terms of $t$ using trigonometric identities.
You might use:

> $$\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x\\\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\implies \cos x=\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$$

to get:

> $$Z=5t\pm8t\sqrt{1-t^2}$$

**This might be solved without calculus, but if possible, I'll add that.**

Comment: You should consider actually that $\cos (x ) = \pm \sqrt{ 1- \sin^2 (x ) }$

Comment: You should probably consider showing OP how to proceed from $5t\pm 8t\sqrt{1-t^2}$ *without* using calculus?

Comment: @KimJongUn I thought calculus would be easy, um will try

Comment: i guess calculus is required now to find the max value of from here on.I want to solve this without the use of calculus.